# Texmaker define xelatex - asymptote - xelatex command

Tags: compiling, texmaker

With texmaker there is a possibility to compile a document with pdflatex-asymptote-pdflatex

[image]

My aim is to define a similaire command but with xelatex engine, usually
 I use xelatex

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I have asymptote in `C:/texlive/2017/bin/win32/asy.exe`

**Minimal Example**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\setmainfont{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{asy}
draw ((0,0) -- (100,100));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can define Quickbuild to do the sequence you prefer. Once you opened the preferences you go to Quick Build. There you chose "User defined" and click on the Wizard.
[image]

[image]

Now you simply add the steps you'd like texmaker to perform in the sequence you prefer.
I hope that helped. :)